# How do I get my RelativeLayout to be as tall as my tallest child?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my inner RelativeLayout to match the size of my tallest child but if I do `wrap_content` or `match_parent`, it just takes up the entire space. The reason I want to have these 2 layouts separate is because if I don't, the EditText will be so transparent that the background of the EditText is the RecyclerView behind it.

Here's my layout files:

layout_edit_text_and_button.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/message_send_edit_ui"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/type_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_message"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send_message"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/type_message"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/send_message"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_chat.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_ui"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/message_send_edit_ui"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/message_send_edit_ui"
        layout="@layout/layout_edit_text_and_button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

The RelativeLayout in layout_edit_text_and_button.xml is only going to affect what's there and the include in fragment_chat.xml won't affected by it.

So you need to manipulate the size in fragment_chat.xml or in code.